# Few ASCII chars are not working in windows application

Tags: java, winforms, ascii

Few ASCII chars i.e. ALT+176 (░) and ALT+202 (╩) are not working in windows application. Instead of the correct symbols, an empty square box is getting typed.

However these ASCII chars are working fine on notepad.
Any Insights, what can be done to get these symbols or is it not possible at all?

Comment: 176 and 202 are Unicode code points, not "ASCII chars". It simply means that the font used by your application has no glyphs for those code points. Also, you do not show the code you use; the problem may also come from there.

Comment: What's the font of the text box that you type Alt+176 in?

Answer (score 1):

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only encodes 128 characters. The characters you refer to are not strictly speaking ASCII characters, they belong to [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII). See this [table](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/graphic-character-low-density-dotted-ascii-code-176.html) too.

Comment: Extended ASCII: [The use of the term is sometimes criticized, because it can be mistakenly interpreted that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, both of which are untrue.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)

Answer (score 1):

Those are from [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). Java uses Unicode.

They [map](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT) to the following Unicode characters:

`░` ['LIGHT SHADE' (U+2591)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2591/index.htm)
  `╩` ['BOX DRAWINGS DOUBLE UP AND HORIZONTAL' (U+2569)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2569/index.htm)